# Display more than 1 image from a file

Tags: php

How do I get it to display the images?

```
  $result = mysqli_query($mdb, "SELECT user FROM `member` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 2");

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
    echo $row[0]; // produces user name 1 no problem
    echo $row[1]; // produces user name 2 no problem
    $src1 = 'uploads/'.$row[0].'image1.jpg'; //gets image1 name under user1
    $src2 = 'uploads/'.$row[1].'image1.jpg'; //gets image1 name under user2
  }
```

Then I need to display it. I've tried HTML

```
  <img src="<?php echo $src1; ?>" id="srca" alt="srca" />
  <img src="<?php echo $src2; ?>" id="srcb" alt="srcb" />
```

The first one appears but the second is just an image box and no image.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason is incorrect path to image or the image/image path is corrupt. Try to open image link in a new window and see what error you get.

Comment: omg, you are right! I just found the error as I saved the file with the same name instead of assigning a 't' to the thumb.